# Problem with EWS API (The server commited a protocol violation)

Tags: vb.net, exchangewebservices

I am trying to make a system for sending email via EWS API. Unfortunately, every time I try to send an email I get this error message:
The request failed. The server committed a protocol violation.. Section=ResponseHeader Detail=CR must be followed by LF.

Here I give the code:

```
        Dim mailFrom As String = "user@domain.com"
        Dim mailPass As String = "userPass"

        Try
            Dim service As ExchangeService = New ExchangeService()
            Dim mail As New EmailMessage(service)

            service.TraceEnabled = True
            service.Credentials = New WebCredentials(mailFrom, mailPass)
            service.Url = New Uri("https://email.domain.com/autodiscover/autodiscover.xml")

            mail.From = mailFrom
            mail.ToRecipients.Add(Email.txtEmailRecipient.Text)
            mail.Subject = Email.txtEmailSubject.Text
            mail.Body = Email.txtEmailBody.Text
            mail.SendAndSaveCopy()

            MsgBox("Email sent.")
        Catch ex As Exception
            MsgBox(ex.Message)
        End Try
    End Sub
```

Thanks in advance for help.

Comment: You need to do more than just show `ex.Message`. What is the **full** exception report? is there any `InnerException`? What's in `ex.Data`? **Use your debugger**.

Comment: There is no InnerException. When I used ex.Data it gives me an error in the console:
Exception thrown: Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.ServiceRequestException in Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.dll
System.Collections.ListDictionaryInternal.
It shows me an error on the line: mail.SendAndSaveCopy().